# Sequences of events

Tags: probability

I saw the following problem:

For any sequence of events $E_1,E_2,E_3, \ldots$, define a new sequence $F_1,F_2, \ldots$ of disjoint events such that for all $n \geq 1$

$$\bigcup_1^nF_i= \bigcup_1^nE_i$$

and well the answer was:

$$F_i=E_i \cap E^c_j$$

but the thing is that is not to clear for me what are the $F_i$, Do you fix $j$?, and well less clearer that  $\bigcup_1^nF_i= \bigcup_1^nE_i$ and that they are disjoint.

Can someone explain me this please?  thanks in advance I appreciate your help :)

Comment: It is commonly defined to be for $i>1$, $F_i = E_i \cap (\bigcap\limits_{j<i} E_j^c)$, or equivalently $F_i = E_i \backslash (\bigcup\limits_{j<i} E_j^c)$ with $F_1 = E_1$

Comment: then this is intersecting all the events before i, then for every i we have a different intersection isn't ?

Comment: and this works even if the sequence is decreasing or increasing ?

Comment: @JMoravitz : If you write $A\setminus B$, with \setminus rather than \backslash, then you get proper spacing before and after the binary operation symbol.  All binary operation and binary relation symbols do that.  Notice the difference between $a+b$ and $a{+}b$.  (The second one is coded as a{+}b so that in effect nothing comes before or after it, so the spacing is not there.)

Answer (score 3):

$F_i=E_i \cap E^c_j$ is not correct.  What is needed is this:
\begin{align}
F_1 & = E_1 \\
F_2 & = \text{the set of all members of $E_2$ that are not in $F_1$} \\
F_3 & = \text{the set of all members of $E_3$ that are not in $F_1\cup F_2$} \\
F_4 & = \text{the set of all members of $E_3$ that are not in $F_1\cup F_2\cup F_3$} \\
& \text{and so on.}
\end{align}
At the $n$th step you include all members of $E_n$ that have not already been included.

For now I'll leave it as an exercise to write that in mathematical notation.

Comment: thanks michael Hardy :)tomorrow when I get my attempt can I ask you for verification?

Comment: Certainly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Will the kind of sequence be important?, or it works fine it doesn't matter is it is increasing or decreasing

Comment: @user162343 It won't matter.  It is possible depending on the sets $E_i$ that one or more of the $F_j$ are the empty set, but that is fine.  The empty set is by definition disjoint from every other set (including itself).  In particular, if $E_1\supset E_2\supset\cdots \supset E_n$, then $F_1=E_1$ and $F_i=\emptyset$ for all $i>1$

Comment: good then this will work fine with every sequence :)